# Oracle RATIO_TO_REPORT and Rollup

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT HOME_DEPT, LINECODE, SUM(TOTAL_HRS),  
       TO_CHAR ( 
       100*RATIO_TO_REPORT(SUM(TOTAL_HRS))
       OVER (PARTITION BY HOME_DEPT), 
       '990.00L', 'NLS_CURRENCY=%'
       ) PCT_JOB
       FROM TABLE 
       GROUP BY HOME_DEPT, LINECODE ORDER BY HOME_DEPT ASC, PCT_JOB DESC;
```

The above Oracle query works and produces results as such:

```
DEPT1 LINECODE1 100 50% 
DEPT1 LINECODE2  50 25%
DEPT1 LINECODE3  50 25%

DEPT2 LINECODE1  20 12.5% 
DEPT2 LINECODE2  20 12.5%
DEPT2 LINECODE3  20 12.5%
DEPT2 LINECODE4  20 12.5%
DEPT2 LINECODE5  20 12.5%
DEPT2 LINECODE6  20 12.5%
DEPT2 LINECODE7  20 12.5%
DEPT2 LINECODE8  20 12.5%
```

now I want to rollup per department to get results as such:

```
DEPT1 LINECODE1 100  50% 
DEPT1 LINECODE2  50  25%
DEPT1 LINECODE3  50  25%
DEPT1           200 100%  <--- desired

DEPT2 LINECODE1  20  12.5% 
DEPT2 LINECODE2  20  12.5%
DEPT2 LINECODE3  20  12.5%
DEPT2 LINECODE4  20  12.5%
DEPT2 LINECODE5  20  12.5%
DEPT2 LINECODE6  20  12.5%
DEPT2 LINECODE7  20  12.5%
DEPT2 LINECODE8  20  12.5%
DEPT2           160 100.0%    <--- desired
```

I have tried various things such as GROUPING SETS but then my PCT_JOB values are wrong.

Comment: I think you need to wrap this in an outer query that does the rollup.

Comment: you were right.  I got it to work, but now I want to order the percentages decending but have the rollup per dept line listed after all the descending percentages. But since the rollup is 100% it is listed first.

Comment: I think you can do something like `...ORDER BY CASE WHEN PCT=100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS PCT END` Not sure if the syntax is 100% but I'm pretty sure it *is* possible to have an expression in an order clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a function `GROUPING` which is [documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions062.htm#i77498). This function will tell you if a given row is a "super-aggregate" row or not. You can then order based on the value of that row.

Note that my definition for the PCT_JOB column is a little bit of a kludge because I am grouping the normal rows and the "super-aggregate" rows separately.

The SQL query below should give you what you need.

```
select
  home_dept,
  linecode,
  total_hrs,
  to_char(
    100 * ratio_to_report(total_hrs) over (partition by home_dept, linecode_group),
    '990.00L', 'NLS_CURRENCY=%') as pct_job 
from (
  SELECT 
    HOME_DEPT, 
    LINECODE, 
    SUM(TOTAL_HRS) as total_hrs, 
    grouping(linecode) as linecode_group
  FROM my_TABLE 
  GROUP BY grouping sets ((home_dept), (HOME_DEPT, LINECODE))
)
ORDER BY HOME_DEPT ASC, linecode_group, pct_job desc
```

Also, I have used grouping sets here but it would be possible to just use:

```
  GROUP BY home_dept, rollup(LINECODE)
```

A [SQLFiddle is available](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ce94/27) which will let you see an example.

Comment: Thanks, OK so your query is working too. Mine (above) works after applying FrustratedWithFormsDesigner suggestion of wrapping in outer query.  But both queries are don't provide the pct_job in a descending order but with the rollup last. See comments on my Question above.  I've been playing with the case but I can't get it to match '100.00%'

Comment: OK, I got the ORDER BY CASE to work. I had to change TO_CHAR to TRUNC so that the WHEN Clause was working on a number not a character.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to update that. It was right on the SQLFiddle page but not in the answer. Fixed now. Please don't use CASE in the ordering but use the GROUPING instead as CASE could cause problems if you only have one row for a given department since the ordering might then be non-deterministic

Comment: yep that works. Thanks.  I could not check out SQLFiddle, my company blocks the site as uncategorized

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer that doesn't require an outer query.  It is based on Mike Meyers' answer, but now the GROUPING of linecode is specified within the PARTITION BY clause and also within the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT
    home_dept,
    linecode,
    SUM(total_hrs) AS total_hrs, 
    TO_CHAR(100 * RATIO_TO_REPORT (SUM(total_hrs))
            OVER (PARTITION BY home_dept, GROUPING(linecode)),
            '990.00L', 'NLS_CURRENCY=%') AS pct_job
FROM my_table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((home_dept), (home_dept, linecode))
ORDER BY home_dept, GROUPING(linecode), pct_job DESC
```

The above code uses GROUP BY GROUPING SETS but the following GROUP BY would also work:

```
GROUP BY home_dept, ROLLUP(linecode)
```

Also FYI: The original question wanted the linecodes sorted in descending order by their percent, not by linecode value (i.e. linecode name).... but in the given example, the results of "descending by percent" looked the same as "ascending by name."  If someone wants to see the linecodes in ascending order by name regardless of percent, you can change the ORDER BY line to this:

```
ORDER BY home_dept, linecode
```

Comment: thanks. I'll be revisiting this app in the near future and can test your query then.