# How can I add add subtotals to Oracle Query which uses ratio_to_report?

Tags: oracle, analytical

I am trying to add totals to a moderately simple query which contains RATIO_TO_REPORT. I reviewed the [Stack solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196270/oracle-ratio-to-report-and-rollup) (among others) and I was unable to make it work in with my query.

My query is;

```
select category, sum(selected_widgets) sum_selected_widgets, to_char(round(RATIO_TO_REPORT(sum(selected_widgets)) over (),4)*100,'999d99') || '%' percentage_selected, 
       count(*) widget_count, to_char(round(RATIO_TO_REPORT(count(*)) over (),4)*100,'999d99') || '%' percentage_all_widgets
from
(
  select widget_id, widget_seq, decode(widget_category,'1100',1,'2372',1,'2650',1,'3932',1,0) selected_widgets, min(category) category
  from widget
  inner join widget_detail wd on wd.widget_id = widget_id and wd.widget_seq = widget_seq and category is not null
  where widget_dx_date between '2018    ' and '20219999'
  group by widget_id, widget_seq, decode(widget_category,'1100',1,'2372',1,'2650',1,'3932',1,0)
)iq
group by category
order by 1;
```

All I am trying to do is get totals for the last 4 columns. If I add "rollup" to the group by, it uses the rollup row as part of the percentage calculations, as shown here;

```
0   6886       3.20%    77871      5.32%
1   40689     18.91%    256538    17.54%
2   8898       4.13%    43615      2.98%
3   9817       4.56%    52809      3.61%
4   5087       2.36%    24683      1.69%
7   27397     12.73%    169669    11.60%
8   4451       2.07%    24148      1.65%
9   4371       2.03%    82084      5.61%
    107596    50.00%    731417    50.00%
```

How can I add totals to this query?

Comment: `group by rollup(category)`  i think that is the syntax for oracle, check it out

Comment: @jorgeCampos The data provided is the output when using rollup(category). As you can see it uses the total line in the calculation of the individual percentages.

Comment: are you sure? I just summed up all columns values and they all match the rollup row result (the exception being the percentage which is being rounded up from 49.99 to 50), for instance the first column: 6886+40689+8898+9817+5087+27397+4451+4371 = 107596

Comment: Also can you show from the result you are having what exactly you want it to be? because after that I feel that what you asked is not really correct explained. As in post the desired result you are expecting

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks for your input. I was able to get an answer, which I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I found another [Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62231205/oracle-sql-group-by-rollup-and-ratio-to-report) which did not help until I clicked the [DB Fiddle link and analyzed the code](https://dbfiddle.uk/x5tGzI6j).

What I was missing was that yes I needed rollup, but I also needed;

1. The case statement in the ratio_to_report clause.
2. The coalesce, to handle the null.

My best explanation, please correct my errors, I will update this answer.

The case statement tells the ratio_to_report to only count grouping_id category and ignore the total line.

Comment: Glad to know that my suggestion was helpful. I would recommend for the sake of completeness that you add to this answer the final version of your query. So for future reference it will be useful to others! Cheers!